# What is the execution ordering of jQuery.empty()?

Tags: jquery

The content of my variable is empty (at the beginning of the code), because of an .empty() method is called at the bottom of the code. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/kC7tD/1/

```
<div id="fixture"></div>
<script>
"use strict";

var GREETING_INPUT = "<input type='text' class='js-greeting-input' />";
var GREETING_MESSAGE = "<div class='js-greeting-message'></div>";

var $fixture = $("#fixture");

console.log("before");
$fixture.append(GREETING_INPUT);
// $fixture is empty!
// if we remove "$fixture.empty()" at the bottom, $fixture is not empty.
console.log($fixture);

console.log("after");
$fixture.empty();
console.log($fixture);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console is not a flat text output device as one might think. Rather, when you log an object, you are asking for a dynamic reference to the object to be placed in the output window--not a snapshot of the object as it was at logging time.

When you `empty` the jQuery object, the dynamic reference that you already logged reflects this.

If you were able to pause execution after your first log statement, you would see that your variable contains what you expected. However, the rest of the code runs before you have a chance to do that.

It's just like the following:

```
var a = {value: true};
var c = a; // "logging" a
delete a.value; // emptying a
// examine c and it is empty
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the console. When you dump out an object, the console (sometimes) shows you a *live* copy of the object, and so if you're looking at it after all the code runs, that live copy has been updated. The console display isn't like a terminal window; the browser (may) update what it's showing you as that thing changes.

So it's not that `$fixture` was empty when you did your second `console.log` after the `append`, it's that the console was updated when you did `$fixture.empty()` later.